# How do I fix python chat program that able to send and receive simultaneously?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to code a python chat program that is able to send and receive simultaneously. Please help me figuring it out.

Here's my code:

```
def button_click():
    q,addr=s.accept()
    a = E2.get()
    w.insert(END, "\nYour message" + a)

    q.send(a)
    E2.delete(0,END)
    looprec()

def looprec():
    while 1:
        msg = q.recv(1024)
        if not msg:
            print ''
        else:
            w.insert(END,"\n Client reply:" + msg)
    s.close()
```

Comment: I am not sure about python but use asynchronous I/O

Answer (score 1):

The code you've included with your question simply wouldn't run. So I'm just going to offer you the two solutions to your problem.

[1. You can use threads!](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=7910020&fromSeriesID=791)

Threads run concurrently. Simultaneously with the main process. They also share the same memory. So a list defined at the head of your Python script can be used to collect the incoming socket connections and then iterated over when you need to broadcast/write to them.

[2. You can use non blocking (sometimes called asynchronous) IO!](http://www.binarytides.com/code-chat-application-server-client-sockets-python/)

Non blocking IO uses features of the underlying operating system. On Linux this is provided by the [epoll system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll) which you can access in Python via [select](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html). epoll allows you to be notified when a socket has content ready to be read from it. Allowing your main process to continue doing other things in the mean time.

Either approach will work. Non blocking IO is generally the most efficient and easiest to reason about.